# Am I forgetting something? (Double Console Buffer for Windows)

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I was trying to make/test a double buffer for console on windows using `windows.h`.

After some research on msdn I came up with this:

`

```
//Free current console
if ( FreeConsole() == 0 ) return GetLastError();
//Get clean console
if ( AllocConsole() == 0 ) return GetLastError();

HANDLE buffer1 = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
HANDLE buffer2 = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer( GENERIC_WRITE,
                                            0,
                                            NULL,
                                            CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
                                            NULL );
COORD begin;
begin.X = 0;
begin.Y = 0;

SetConsoleCursorPosition(buffer1, begin);

DWORD writen;

WriteConsole( buffer1,
              L"Milk\n",
              5,
              &writen,
              NULL );

WriteConsole( buffer2,
              L"Melk\n",
              5,
              &writen,
              NULL );

system("PAUSE");

SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer( buffer2 );

WriteConsole( buffer2,
              L"Malk\n",
              5,
              &writen,
              NULL );

WriteConsole( buffer1,
              L"Mulk\n",
              5,
              &writen,
              NULL );

system("PAUSE");

SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer( buffer1 );

system("PAUSE");
CloseHandle( buffer2 );
return 0; //End of main
```

Thankfully this is working as intended.

First the screen output is just:

```
Milk
```

Then it's:

```
Melk
Malk
```

And finishing off:

```
Milk
Mulk
```

And I have a few questions about this:

1) Is the `FreeConsole()` and `AllocConsole()` at the start really necessary?

2) Should I be using `CloseHandle()` for buffer1 too? Or shouldn't I even be using it for buffer2?

3) Anything else you think it's important to point out.

PS: This is my first question and I hope I'm not breaking any guidelines.

PS²: I only used `system("PAUSE")` because this was a test and you shouldn't worry about me using it in actual software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answers in case anyone is interested:

1) I found out that makes no difference at all. However if you execute your program from the cmd that will make sure that another console pops out.

2) The `CloseHandle()` should only be used for the console screen buffer. The standard output is dealt with automatically.